# Referring to html element

Tags: vba

Could you tell me what's wrong with this code:

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As Object, html As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://pl.pons.com/tłumaczenie"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set html = .document

        With html

            .getElementsByTagName("span")(22).Click
            .getElementsByTagName("span")(109).Click
            .getElementByID("q").Value = "rower"
            .querySelector("button.btn.btn-primary.submit").Click
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
            translation = .getElementsByTagName("dd")(0).innerText

            Stop
        End With
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

It works but translation returns nothing. I use late binding and I can't change it.

Comment: On my end `translation` contains text (incorrect one, because you refer to wrong element on page, but it does). Problem can be with no `While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend` loop after clicks.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know HTML and that's why I don't know how to refer to this element. I guess that it's the first element and as you wrote enumaration starts from 0 that's why I put 0 and I use dd as name. I've tried many times, I searched the Internet but the way I do this leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: Seems fine to me. When I run this code `translation` is `" rzeczownik  "`. I don't speak Polish, but that seems correct to me. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I use translation = .querySelector("dd > div > div > a").innerText and it works well, if I change words I receive translation in my variable. Problem is with verbs because infinitive in English consists of two words "to" +verb and using this syntax I get only "to". What I want to accomplish is to create dynamic application, I mean if I translate a noun I receive a noun and when I translate a verb I receive two words: "to"+verb.

Comment: I removed my answer as it used output structure from url containing "tłumaczenie-tekstu" not "tłumaczenie".